# How to fix NumberFormatException in Java?

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I am trying to find the center of a Tetris piece for a T-Spin.

EDIT: Error log:

```
04-08 22:53:13.078 8438-8438/com.example.tetris000 E/MYAPP: exception
                                                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4.0"
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
at com.example.tetris000.MainActivity.getCenter(MainActivity.java:1457)
at com.example.tetris000.MainActivity.checkLine(MainActivity.java:1500)
at com.example.tetris000.MainActivity.lockPiece(MainActivity.java:1704)
at com.example.tetris000.MainActivity.hardDrop(MainActivity.java:1242)
at com.example.tetris000.MainActivity.onDropClick(MainActivity.java:1209)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
04-08 22:53:15.909 8438-8438/com.example.tetris000 E/MYAPP: exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4.0"
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
at com.example.tetris000.MainActivity.getCenter(MainActivity.java:1457)
at com.example.tetris000.MainActivity.checkLine(MainActivity.java:1500)
at com.example.tetris000.MainActivity.lockPiece(MainActivity.java:1704)
at com.example.tetris000.MainActivity$7.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:1732)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Finally `getCenter()` function:

```
public void getCenter(Boolean rotateRight){;
        double placeholder;
        double rounded = (rotation.point1.x + rotation.point2.x + rotation.point3.x + rotation.point4.x);
        double roundedX = rounded / 4;
        rounded = (rotation.point1.y + rotation.point2.y + rotation.point3.y + rotation.point4.y); // Divison error fixed
        double roundedY = rounded / 4; //Problem is that it will sometimes be roundedY = 12.25 and we need to fix it so it rounds down to 12 or up to 13, but increment is only 0.1

        if(rotation.rotateAmount == 0){
            roundedY *= 100;
            placeholder = roundedY;
            roundedY -= placeholder % 100;
            roundedY /= 100;
            roundedX *= 100;
            if(roundedX % 100 != 0) {
                placeholder = roundedX;
                if(rotateRight) {
                    if (roundedX % 100 >= 50) {
                        roundedX += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
                    } else {
                        roundedX -= placeholder % 100;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (roundedX % 100 > 50) {
                        roundedX += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
                    } else {
                        roundedX -= placeholder % 100;
                    }
                }
            }
            roundedX /= 100;
        } else if(rotation.rotateAmount == 1){
            roundedX *= 100;
            placeholder = roundedX;
            roundedX -= placeholder % 100;
            roundedX /= 100;
            roundedY *= 100;
            if(roundedY % 100 != 0) {
                placeholder = roundedY;
                if(rotateRight) {
                    if (roundedY % 100 <= 50) {
                        roundedY -= placeholder % 100;
                    } else {
                        roundedY += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (roundedY % 100 < 50) {
                        roundedY -= placeholder % 100;
                    } else {
                        roundedY += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
                    }
                }
            }
            roundedY /= 100;
        } else if(rotation.rotateAmount == 2){
            roundedY *= 100;
            placeholder = roundedY;
            if(100 - (placeholder % 100) == 100 || 100 - (placeholder % 100) == 0){} else {
                roundedY += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
            }
            roundedY /= 100;
            roundedX *= 100;
            if(roundedX % 100 != 0) {
                placeholder = roundedX;
                if(rotateRight) {
                    if (roundedX % 100 <= 50) {
                        roundedX -= placeholder % 100;
                    } else {
                        roundedX += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (roundedX % 100 < 50) {
                        roundedX -= placeholder % 100;
                    } else {
                        roundedX += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
                    }
                }
            }
            roundedX /= 100;
        } else if(rotation.rotateAmount == 3){
            roundedX *= 100;
            placeholder = roundedX;
            if(100 - (placeholder % 100) == 100 || 100 - (placeholder % 100) == 0){} else {
                roundedX += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
            }
            roundedX /= 100;
            roundedY *= 100;
            if(roundedY % 100 != 0) {
                placeholder = roundedY;
                if(rotateRight) {
                    if (roundedY % 100 >= 50) {
                        roundedY += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
                    } else {
                        roundedY -= placeholder % 100;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (roundedY % 100 > 50) {
                        roundedY += 100 - (placeholder % 100);
                    } else {
                        roundedY -= placeholder % 100;
                    }
                }
            }
            roundedY /= 100;
        }
        centerX = Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(roundedX));
        centerY = Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(roundedY));
    }
```

Comment: try printing out the exception - heaps of information there

Comment: Okay I think I did it :)

Comment: Very strange that you realized that you had a error in `getCenter` but you posted all code **but** `getCenter` - anyway, the exception tells you why and where doesn't it.

Comment: I don't necessarily understand most crash reports and when I looked them up, it didn't help. Pretty new to Java and Android Studio and by no means professional, still a student and learning! Can you please explain the error?

Comment: You can't parse the string representation of a `double` as an `int`, and you don't need to. You just need `centerX = (int)roundedX;` *et simile*. None of the parsing stuff. You also need to learn how to read stack traces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error message seems pretty self explanatory:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4.0"
       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt()
```

Your string looks like floating point value, not integer.

**EDIT**

In fact this parsing

```
centerX = Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(roundedX));
```

is not needed at all as you can cast double to int directly:

```
centerX = (int)roundedX;
```

See [type casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)

Comment: Why would you convert a `double` to a `String` only to convert it back again? The problem is far simpler than this. All that is needed is a typecast.

Comment: You're calling `Double.parseDouble()`. QED. `Double.parseDouble()` requires a `String`. Where did it come from? Your answer implies `Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(roundedX))`, which is a complete waste of time and space. `(int)roundedX` is sufficient. There is no typecast in your answer, no matter how many times you read it.

Comment: From here `For input string: "4.0"`

Comment: No. It came from the OP's code, and specifically from `Double.toString(roundedX)`. You are quoting the error message that resulted from trying to parse the string that resulted from that. You are putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Haven't read his code, just stacktrace. And true, parsing is not needed in such case. For some reason I assumed he got that value from the user as this is common issue

Comment: So at the moment this isn't even an answer. You haven't identified the underlying problem, and you've provided no solution.